# Unable to connect to Facebook through Docker container

Tags: angular, facebook, docker

I have a simple Angular app in which I am using the Facebook SDK. The app is setup to run inside a Docker container.
When I do a **docker-compose up** I am able to open my app in localhost.xxxx.com:4201 But, when I click on the Facebook login button, I receive the error - 'Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.'

However, when I do an **ng serve**, my app opens in localhost:4200 After clicking the Facebook login button, I am able to connect to Facebook and also get a response.

I am unable to figure out how to make the Facebook login work from inside the Docker container. Any help would be much appreciated.

My Facebook app settings are:
Site URL : http://localhost:4201/

App Domains : localhost

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of adding localhost.xxxx.com:4201 to your facebook app domain settings?

Comment: Hi @David, Thanks for your advice.
So, after adding ‘localhost.xxxx.com’ to the list of App domains, noticed that with ng serve the app opens on port 4200 (which is the default)
Deleting just the ‘localhost’ entry from the App domains list, causes the error ‘Can't Load URL…’ (which is understandable)
Executing a **‘docker-compose up’** Facebook login returns an error that the URL "https://localhost.xxxx.com:4201/f2...918" ‘ has been blocked by Facebook. This is for both the above mentioned App domain settings. My app is still in ‘Development’ stage and is not made public. Working on it.